# Link Person Account to an Object (PRODUCT)

Tags: opportunity, account, automation, person-accounts, product

As a sports agent I have both BTB clients (Sports Club which are Club ACCOUNT) and BTC clients (Athletes who are person account Athlete Account).
My Athlete accounts are also products as I m offering them to Sports clubs requirements (BTB opportunities).
How can i do to link an "athlete account" (person account) to a product and create a portfolio of products (a client list as we say in my industry).

Thank you

Comment: If your athlete is a "product", the Account record (Person Account or plain business Account) is not the representation of that product. You need more entities in your data model. Standard [Sales Data Model](https://architect.salesforce.com/diagrams/template-gallery/sales-cloud-overview-data-model) has Product, PriceBook and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard Sales Cloud Product object and you simply wanted to link one Athlete to a product so you could use formulas to get information from the person Account which includes both the account and contact information which are fused into the person account you would just put a lookup custom field for account on the product object.  You would probably want to filter so only Athlete accounts could be chosen and not club accounts. The picture shows what that looks like.

[image: Setting up the Athlete account lookup with filter]